# C# Saving password as string safely for Oracle Database connection?

Tags: c#, oracle, security, passwords, odp.net

I am trying to connect to Oracle database using ODP.net in C#.

```
string myuserid;
string mypw;
string connstring =
  "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost)(PORT=1527))" +
  "(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mysid)));User Id=" + myuserid + ";Password=" + mypw + ";";
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstring))
```

I want to use windows form to get myuserid and mypw  to use it in a query.

What would be the best way to store this information during the session securely?
Is it possible to remove this string after certain time of inactivity?

Thank you in advance..

Comment: @Lukas that does not apply here. If it were a fixed connection string then encrypting that part of the config file would work. However if the user entered the authentication details there are different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ProtectedData.Protect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fh8203k.aspx) to encrypt data in a way that is tied to the local user profile (ie. will only work for the current user on the current machine).

This can then be saved locally, and then passed through `ProtectedData.Unprotect` to get the password back to build a new connection string.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. After I posted the question I was trying to use SecureString(). How safe is this approach?  After user's input, I save it in SecureString and when I need it, i use SecureString.toString() then use clear to remove the string.

Comment: `SecureString` is good while the process is in memory – avoids the password being visible in memory. Use of `ProtectedData` allows securely saving the password.